# How do I cast a string to an array

Tags: php, arrays

So as you can see below I have an array that I get from an ajax request.. Now is my question how can I use the [name] as an array? The arrays below are two different arrays

Changing the arrays below is done in PHP

So this:

```
( 
   [name] => template[options][4892][is_delete]
   [value] => 1
)
( 
   [name] => template[options][4892][name]
   [value] => just_a_name
)
```

Into this

```
( 
   [template] => (
        [options] => (
             [4892] => (
                 name => just_a_name,
                 is_delete => 1
             )
        )
    )
)
```

Edited: changed value to is_delete

Edit2: changed some things to make it more clear

Hope this is clear enough

Comment: Where you lost your `is_delete` ?

Comment: This is very unclear. First: what a horrible data source, I feel with you. Who implements such thing?!? What is unclear in your description is the mapping of the values. You map both values different, so there is no clear rule to be seen and implemented... In the first element the key is `value`, in the second `name`, that does not match up. The `is_delete` appears to be ignored... In short: this is a mess ;-) Could you please take the time to be more precise? Thanks!

Comment: What does php have to do with ajax?

Comment: @AdamForbis The data is coming from an ajax request, its actually irrelevant where its from as it has nothing to do with what i want to accomplish

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = [
    [
        'name' => 'template[options][4892][is_delete]',
        'value' => 1
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'template[options][4892][name]',
        'value' => 'name'
    ]
];

$parsedData = [];

foreach ($data as $item) {
    parse_str($item['name'] . '=' . $item['value'], $out);
    $parsedData = array_replace_recursive($parsedData, $out);
}

print_r($parsedData);
```

result:

```
Array(
    [template] => Array(
        [options] => Array(
            [4892] => Array(
                [is_delete] => 1
                [name] => name
            )
        )
    )
)
```